# jqgrid search: How to specify search column?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, jqgrid, filter

I am using jqgrid on EF4 MVC3 (C#). I based search on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/1129461) @Oleg 's solution, which works fine and fits for my needs.

I have the following columns defined in my grid:

```
          ...
          { name: 'Stato', index: 'StatoTicketID', width: 20, align: 'left', sorttype: 'int', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq']} },
          { name: 'StatoTicketID', index: 'StatoTicketID', width: 20, align: 'left', sorttype: 'int', hidden: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq']} },
          ...
```

As you can see, the column `Stato` is ordered by the index `StatoTicketID` (hidden integer field) and ordering works fine.

**PROBLEM**

When I try to search a value of `Stato`, the filter is passed on index `StatoTicketID` as string, while I'd like to search by `Stato` values. So I get an exception inside the controller which specifies that I cannot convert String type to Int32.

Does exist a way to specify on which column apply search, when index is on a different column, like in my case?

**EDIT & WORKAROUND:**
For now I solved my problem with the following workaround.

```
        (inside foreach (Rule rule in rules) of FilterObjectSet by Oleg)
         ....

         if (rule.field == "StatoTicketID")
            {
                rule.field = "StatoTicket.Stato";
                propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty("stringfield"); // where stringfield is a text type column of my model
            }
```

I realize very well that is not an elegant solution, I expect a kind response by you, to know how to implement the required behaviour directly from jqGrid, please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you chosen too complex way. I would just send to the client (to the jqGrid) only the `Stato` and have to `StatoTicketID` at all. From the design point of your the `StatoTicketID` is the part of the server implementation and the client should not depend from this.

If you have Unique Constrain (or unique index) on `Stato` column of the `StatoTickets` table you would very quickly find the `StatoTicketID` whenever you as need. So the jqGrid can contain and "know" only about `Stato` and have no information about the `StatoTicketID` as the implementation detail.

One more way to solve the problem is the usage of `formatter: 'select'` in the column `Stato`. It's important to understand that in the case the mapping between `Stato` text and the `StatoTicketID` should be loaded *before* the grid is created. In the case the `Stato` column should have the properties like

```js
formatter: 'select', edittype: 'select', editoptions: {value: '12:Stato1;24:Stato2'},
stype: 'select', searchoptions: {value: ':All;12:Stato1;24:Stato2'}
```

One can't use `dataUrl` in the case instead of `value` in the `editoptions`.

As the result you will be able to fill column `Stato` with the `StatoTicketID` data, but the corresponding texts will displayed by jqGrid.

I recommend you better to implement the first way with pure `Stato` text. All the problems you would be able to solve only on the server part.

Comment: Thank you very much Oleg! I'll try the second way. I understand and I share your concerns regarding the solution I adopted, probably because I have not specified a detail: `StatoTicketID` allows me to place an order on the basis of 'priority' given to the `Stato` field, so a pure text sort order is no good in my case.

I am going to try the second way: I think it's the best solution in my case. I'll keep you updated! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Larry: You are welcome! If you use `datatype: 'json'` without `loadonce: true` you implement the sorting of the server side so you can continue to use `name: 'Stato', index: 'StatoTicketID'` even after the usage of pure text values in the `'Stato'` column. If you will choose the second way you will be careful with the data which will be posted to the server in case of editing the `'Stato'` column. Let me know whether you will implement all till the end solution.

Comment: THX. I tried to implement the first solution, but it still does not work. I already used datatype: 'json' and loadonce: false...pheraps must I modify your solution?
I am trying the second one...I'll keep you updated, THX!

Comment: THX Oleg! It works fine now! I followed your precious hints. I implemented as you suggested, changing the static text with dynamic one, using `surl`. THX!

Comment: @Larry: You are welcome! I am glad to know that the problem is solved now.